# Highlighting rows based upon two adjacent cells being different but specific numbers

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am trying to put together a conditional formula for an Excel spreadsheet. What I need is for the row to highlight when cells A2 and B2 are two different, but specific numbers. For example, I want the second row highlighted when the value in  A2 is exactly 12345 and when the adjacent value in B2 is exactly 67890. I do not want the row highlighted if the value in A2 is anything other than 12345 and the value in B2 is anything other than 67890. There are about 3,500 rows of numbers, so I am trying to speed up the process. I will eventually have to do the opposite, and see when the value in A2 is 67890 and when the value in B2 is 12345.

In order to clear up any questions, I am looking at an Excel document tracking phone calls made over a long period of time, and I want to highlight the whole row when two different phone numbers are calling each other among all the other phone calls.

Answer (score 1):

With conditional formatting, you can use formulas.  Highlight a row (let's say row 2 to start), and in Conditional Formatting, under "Use a formula...", `=and($b2<>$a2,$a2=12345,$b2=67890)`.

If you apply that to your whole range (a2:b100, let's say), if the cell in A and B are different, and then only if A and B are the numbers you want, will the row be highlighted.

edit: added absolute cell references.  Also, see @Grade'Eh'Bacon's comment.

Comment: I think this should actually be: OR(AND($B2=67890,$A2=12345),AND($B2=12345,$A2=67890)) - note that the column references must be absolute, with $'s, because we don't want the rule to change for columns later than A. Remember that conditional formatting is written relative to the top-left cell in the selected rule's application area.

Comment: Ah, yes, good looking out.  I'll update my post.  I couldn't quite tell from his OP what he was looking for but between your post and mine, he should be able to work it out I think.